# KendoUI grid modify cell removes selection

Tags: kendo-ui

Modifying an element using `set` of a KendoUI grid removes the selection.

If a have a KendoUI `DataSource` defined as:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data    : [
        { "id": 1, "item": "item1", "value": "foo" },
        { "id": 2, "item": "item2", "value": "foo" },
        { "id": 3, "item": "item3", "value": "foo" },
        { "id": 4, "item": "item4", "value": "foo" }
    ],
    pageSize: 5
});
```

and the `grid` as:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns   : [
        { field: "item", title: "Item" },
        { field: "value", title: "Value" }
    ],
    selectable: "row"
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

If I click in a row (select it) and then update the model using the following code:

```
dataSource.data()[0].set("value", "bar");
```

The selection gets lost.

Sample code in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/DELNw/1/)

Instructions:

1. Select any row.
2. Click the button for changing the `value` of the first row.

Is there any way of preserving selection when updating a local `DataSource`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior when a change event of the dataSource occurs the Grid reacts and it is redrawn. You can silently update the field like this:

```
dataSource.data()[0].value = "bar";
```

However this will not trigger the change event and the Grid wont be updated either.

To preserve the selection of the Grid between 'refreshes' you can use the approach covered in [this](http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/web/grid/preserve-grid-state-in-a-cookie.aspx) code library article. You can store them in a cookie or in the memory, it is up to you.

Regards

Comment: Sure that there is good reason for this behavior but looks pretty odd to me that this is the expected. Anyhow answer accepted.

Comment: The Grid does not know anything about selection - it is just CSS class. Once the Grid elements are re-created the class is gone. It is as simple as that.

Comment: I know and I understand that for simplicity it is easier to redraw the full row. But in this case the selection gets removed and `change` event is not fired. And again I know that we were binding the `change` to the previous version of the row and not the redrawn but this makes programmer have to work thinking on HTML and CSS all the time (and know how KendoUI is implemented).

Comment: I agree with @OnaBai - it feels to me as a Developer that the Kendo grid should handle this without the end-user developer needing to worrying about what exactly the grid is doing.  Surely the grid can re-paint and keep the selection.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find solution for a very similar problem. I tried to select next row after modifying selected row, but updating data item cleared selection.

The trick was to save `data-uid` of the element to be selected. After update, I simply select element by uid.

```js
var selected = grid.select();
var next = selected.next();
var nextUid = next.data("uid");
var dataItem = grid.dataItem(selected);
if (dataItem) {
    dataItem.set("value", dataItem.get("value") - 1);
    if (next.length)
        grid.select($("#grid").find("*[data-uid='" + nextUid + "']"));
}
```

[You can try it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/r2L0smu9/3/)